# MongoDB Python Twitter streaming not saving to database

Tags: python, mongodb, api, twitter, streaming

Trying to create a python script that will datamine twitter, but Im not having good luck! I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import datetime

# Auth Variables

consumer_key = "INSERT_KEY_HERE"
consumer_key_secret = "INSERT_KEY_HERE"
access_token = "INSERT_KEY_HERE"
access_token_secret = "INSERT_KEY_HERE"

# MongoDB connection info

connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection.TwitterStream
db.tweets.ensure_index("id", unique=True, dropDups=True)
collection = db.tweets

# Key words to be tracked, (hashtags)

keyword_list = ['#MorningAfter', '#Clinton', '#Trump']


class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):

        # Load the Tweet into the variable "t"
        t = json.loads(data)

        # Pull important data from the tweet to store in the database.
        tweet_id = t['id_str']  # The Tweet ID from Twitter in string format
        text = t['text']  # The entire body of the Tweet
        hashtags = t['entities']['hashtags']  # Any hashtags used in the Tweet
        time_stamp = t['created_at']  # The timestamp of when the Tweet was created
        language = t['lang']  # The language of the Tweet

        # Convert the timestamp string given by Twitter to a date object called "created"
        created = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_stamp, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')

        # Load all of the extracted Tweet data into the variable "tweet" that will be stored into the database
        tweet = {'id': tweet_id, 'text': text, 'hashtags': hashtags, 'language': language, 'created': created}

        # Save the refined Tweet data to MongoDB
        collection.insert(tweet)

        print(tweet_id + "\n")
        return True

    # Prints the reason for an error to your console
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

l = StdOutListener(api=tweepy.API(wait_on_rate_limit=True))
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

stream = Stream(auth, listener=l)
stream.filter(track=keyword_list)
```

Here is the script I have so far. I've tried to do a few google searches and I've compared what I have to what they have and can't find the source of the issue. It runs and connects to the MongoDB, I have the correct database created, but nothing is being put in the database. I have a bit of debug code, where it prints the tweet id, but that just prints 401 over and over in about 5-10 sec interval. I tried some basic examples I found while googling what I wanted to do and still nothing happened. I think it might be an issue with the Database connecting? here are some images of the database being run.
[image: This is with the database just started]
[image: This is with the script running]
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally! The printing of 401 was the key here, it's an authentication error. I had to connect my system clock to the internet, and reset my system's clock.